# Given a Dictionary and a list of letters, find all possible words that can be created with the letters

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The function scoreList(Rack) takes in a list of letters. You are also given a global variable Dictionary: `["a", "am", "at", "apple", "bat", "bar", "babble", "can", "foo", "spam", "spammy", "zzyzva"]`.

Using a list of letters find all possible words that can be made with the letters that are in the Dictionary. For each word that can be made also find the score of that word using scrabbleScore.

scrabbleScore =

```
           [ ["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1], 
             ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8], 
             ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1], ["p", 3], 
             ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4], 
             ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10] ]
```

I can use expressions made up of list comprehensions(map, filter, reduce, etc.), if statements, and for loops but only if they are in the context of a list comprehension.

Example:

```
>>> scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"])
[['a', 1], ['am', 4], ['at', 2], ['spam', 8]]
>>> scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "o", "f", "o"])
[['a', 1], ['am', 4], ['foo', 6]]
```

The order in which they are presented does not matter. It also must remain a list and not a dic. Would love some help with this problem or if you could give me a better understanding of how to use map or filter in this problem.

MyCode:

```
def scoreList(Rack):
    test = [x for x in Dictionary if all(y in Rack for y in x)]
    return test
```

Output:

```
>>> scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"])
['a', 'am', 'at', 'spam']
```

As you can see I was able to find the words, but not the score. How could I find it without using dict?

Comment: What are the numbers in your example answers?

Comment: Sadly no, I think I may have worded my problem wrong. You input your own list of letters, any letters. Any word from the Dictionary that can be made with the letters is outputted along with its score. Also I forgot to say that it must remain a list. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` to generate all possible permutations of words from a set of characters, but note if your input list becomes large this will become a lengthy and memory consuming process.

```
import itertools

d = dict([ ["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1],
             ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8],
             ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1], ["p", 3],
             ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4],
             ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10] ])

words = ["a", "am", "at", "apple", "bat", "bar", "babble", "can", "foo", "spam", "spammy", "zzyzva"]

def scoreList(l):
    perms = itertools.chain.from_iterable(list(itertools.permutations(l,r)) for r in range(1,len(l)))
    return [["".join(x),sum(d[c] for c in "".join(x))] for x in set(perms) if "".join(x) in words]

print(scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"]))
# Outputs: [['at', 2], ['a', 1], ['spam', 8], ['am', 4]]

print(scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "o", "f", "o"]))
# Outputs: [['a', 1], ['foo', 6], ['am', 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there anyway to do it without using itertools and not making score into a dictionary that you know of?

Comment: @VinceCarter Why? There are ways of course, you could use list indexing instead of a dictionary, but I would not recommend it. You could write your own itertools or similar in native python, see the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: In all honesty this is homework. However, I have edited my post to what I was able to get until I got stuck.

Comment: The approach to this problem depends highly on the maximum number of letters you are allowed to use and how fast you require an answer. Bear in mind that the number of permutations with 10 letters gets above 3,500,000, and you have to add the permutations for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 letters so you'll be around 4,000,000 of possible words. Comparing each one of those with all the words in a dictionary will be slow as hell.

Comment: So what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code to achieve this:

```
score = [["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1],
         ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8],
         ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1], 
         ["p", 3], ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], 
         ["u", 1], ["v", 4], ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10]]

my_list = ["a", "am", "at", "apple", "bat", "bar", "babble", "can", "foo", "spam", "spammy", "zzyzva"]
score_dict = dict(score)  # Storing score value as dict

def get_word_score(my_list):
    return [(item, sum(score_dict[a] for a in item)) for item in my_list]

get_word_score(my_list)
# returns: [('a', 1), ('am', 4), ('at', 2), ('apple', 9), ('bat', 5), ('bar', 5), ('babble', 12), ('can', 5), ('foo', 6), ('spam', 8), ('spammy', 15), ('zzyzva', 39)]
```